# Java Constructor not defined

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Trying to send an email through my test, it calls on this class as the main one.

```
public class SendMail{
public SendMail(String fromMail,String tomail, Exception e )
{
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("abc123@gmail.com","testpw");
    }
});
try {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromMail));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(tomail));
    message.setSubject("xxxxx");
    message.setText("xxxxx"+ ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e) );
    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Done");
}
    catch (MessagingException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
}
public SendMail(String string, String line) {
```

So I want to call this in my other class, to be able to pull a list of emails from a txt file so it will email everything on the list. That code is:

```
String fileName = "/xxx/xxx/xxx/text.txt";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
    new SendMail("abcd@gmail.com", line);
}   

  }
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that it's telling me the constructor SendMail(String, String) is undefined.

My orginal code works but this only allows me to send hard coded emails.

```
try{
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
new SendMail("senderemail","reciveremail",e); } 
}
```

Why won't it accept my constructor?

EDIT: The consturctor was not wrong. I was! I found the reason why It wouldn't work and solved my issue. This is the code I'm using now that works.

```
String fileName = "/Users/cdolan/Desktop/liness.txt";
String Email = "";

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)))      {

     while ((Email = br.readLine()) !=null)

     {

<Test code here goes here>

 }
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    new SendMail("email123@gmail.com",Email,e); }
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that it's telling me the constructor SendMail(String, String) is undefined." That's probably because you never defined a `SendMail(String, String)` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you only define the method `SendMail(String fromMail,String tomail, Exception e)` so you cant call a method that is not defined.

You need to define and implement the method`SendMail(String fromMail,String tomail,)` so you can call it!

Another question should be: for what reason do you need to pass the exception as a input param?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance I am new to this but whenever I create a new constructor, public SendMail(String, string, String line) { It simply does not even send an email. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Nevermind! Is there any error displayed when you try to send the email?

Comment: No in my original code it will only trigger an email on error in which I wanted it to sent the console log to the email. When I'm trying to do this it simply does not send anything. Did i create the constructor in the wrong place? the second one (String string, String line) is after the throw new RuntimeException  after the brackets.

Comment: Hi! I cant see how you implement the new method, under the declaration of it its empty

Comment: Hi Melli. I actually figured out what was wrong. The Constructor was not wrong I was. I updated my code in the OP to show.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you have specified takes an Exception as an argument (for what reason??). This exception argument is missing when you create a new object.